# Ground influence on 434 MHz radio signal

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, radio-frequency

I have read in a paper that ground acts as reflector for radio signals in 434 MHz band. Why is that the case?

Comment: at low enough grazing angle any surface at any frequency acts as a mirror

Comment: You might try over at the ham radio stackexchange...